# Parse, how to save Appended text

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

Let's say I have the following code:

```
$('.button').click(function() {  
 $('body').append("<p>Random Text</p>");
});
```

Where when the `.button` is clicked, text is appended to the body.

How would I go about saving that text and having it always appear when the user visits the page.
Would it be wise to store it in a variable and then send it to Data Browser under 
`POST` or another Class?

Hope this isn't too confusing, thanks!

Comment: You want to save the text somewhere you will need a persistence layer. Like cookies, clientsideDB, serverside DB, ect.

Comment: yep ^^, I would say use html5 localstorage, that will save the data for a while or until the user clears their cache.  This also eliminates the need to create a db and store the session/data.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't ideal but without creating a server side or clientside db this would be a quick fix.  If the user switches browsers or clears their cache the storage is gone.

http://jsfiddle.net/4gseg96g/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Read localStorage.
    function getStorage() {
        var obj = localStorage.getItem('objName');
        if(!obj) {
            obj = '';
        }
        return obj;
    }
   // Append localStorage obj, if any.
   $('body').append(getStorage());   
   $('.button').click(function() {  
       console.log('click');
       var str = "<p>Random Text</p>";
       $('body').append(str);
       var d = getStorage();
       d += str;
       console.log(d);
       localStorage.setItem('objName', d);
   }); 
});
```